# Is there a way to make a plain chart in DrRacket?

Tags: database, graph, charts, racket, dr.racket

I've been looking for an answer online, but all I've found are ways to plot points and create graphs. I was inspired by this fitness tracker (https://www.reddit.com/r/Racket/comments/5ywuf8/my_hobby_project_in_racket_a_fitness_activity/) I'm trying to make an app that tracks food in a restaurant. So, for instance,

```
Ingredient- Bananas 
Amount- 25 lbs
Servings- 200 (2-oz ea)
MOD- TEJ
```

I want to put the information into a chart, which will later be turned into a graph of food received. Any ideas? It would be great if you could point me a to a source or documentation for how to do this. I'm also wondering if there's anyway to create a nice gui which takes the input from the user. Thank you!

Comment: The app you point to actually includes the Racket code. Have you taken a look at it? (I haven't, maybe you already have?)

Comment: What is a "plain chart"?

Comment: Please provide an example of how the input should be output because it is unclear what you are asking.